# PuLP Conditional Sum

Tags: python-3.x, pulp

I try to model the following mathematical statement in PuLP (part of objective):

[image: Purchase Cost]

Knowing the common notation like

`pulp.lpSum(p.loc[t][tau]*d[t+tau]*q[t][tau] for t in T for tau in F)`

I'm unsure on how to include the condition of `tau` being less or equal than `T - tau`. I've worked with XPRESS before, where I could do something like

`forall(t in T, tau in F | tau<=T-t)`

Now my question would be, whether this is also feasible with PuLP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really related to pulp, but completely driven by python's [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Instead of

```
pulp.lpSum(p.loc[t][tau]*d[t+tau]*q[t][tau] for t in T for tau in F)
```

just use

```
nT = len(T)
pulp.lpSum(p.loc[t][tau]*d[t+tau]*q[t][tau] for t in T for tau in F if tau <= nT-t)
```